# Is there a way to Debug a Store Procedure(SQL server) in real time while running a backend console project?

Tags: sql, sql-server, debugging, stored-procedures, breakpoints

I'm trying to find a bug on a store procedure(SQL server) that gets executed from a console application coded in C#. Is there a way I can do some sort of breakpoints into the Store Procedure scripts and find how the data gets processed into the store procedure in real-time?

I know that you can debug a simply Stored procedure on Visual Studio. But what I want to do it's to debug it in real-time with the console application.

Comment: Yes, it is MS SQL

Answer (score 0):

Dependent on which version of SQL Server you are using you will want to use either [SQL Server Profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-ver16) or Extended Events, see [Quick Start: Extended events in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/quick-start-extended-events-in-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) and [SSMS XEvent Profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/use-the-ssms-xe-profiler?view=sql-server-ver16).